# working with morris charts data source feeding

Tags: javascript

I am working with morris charts and I think that the object is built as expected but nothing is showing up
this is the json i get from the request:

```
[{"y":"2","a":981}],[{"y":"3","a":981}],[{"y":"4","a":987}],[{"y":"5","a":987}],[{"y":"6","a":987}],[{"y":"7","a":987}],[{"y":"8","a":987}],[{"y":"9","a":987}],[{"y":"10","a":987}],[{"y":"11","a":988}],[{"y":"12","a":988}],[{"y":"13","a":988}],[{"y":"14","a":987}],[{"y":"15","a":987}],[{"y":"16","a":987}],[{"y":"17","a":987}],[{"y":"18","a":987}],[{"y":"19","a":988}],[{"y":"20","a":989}],[{"y":"21","a":989}]
```

and this is the js code i wrote so that the format is as expected for the morris chart:

```
data.forEach(function(item) {

    var obj = [];
    obj.push({"y": item[0].y, "a": item[0].a});
    nietos.push(obj[0]);
});

    console.log(nietos);
new Morris.Bar({
    element: 'morrisAreatest',
    data: [nietos],
    xkey: 'y',
    ykeys: ['a'],
    labels: ['Value'],
    barColors: ['#7cbddf'],
    stacked: true,
    gridTextSize: 13,
    hideHover: 'auto',
    resize: true
});
```

the object that is created is:

```
    0: {y: "2", a: 981}
1: {y: "3", a: 981}
2: {y: "4", a: 987}
3: {y: "5", a: 987}
4: {y: "6", a: 987}
5: {y: "7", a: 987}
6: {y: "8", a: 987}
7: {y: "9", a: 987}
8: {y: "10", a: 987}
9: {y: "11", a: 988}
10: {y: "12", a: 988}
11: {y: "13", a: 988}
12: {y: "14", a: 987}
13: {y: "15", a: 987}
14: {y: "16", a: 987}
15: {y: "17", a: 987}
16: {y: "18", a: 987}
17: {y: "19", a: 988}
18: {y: "20", a: 989}
19: {y: "21", a: 989}
```

this object I added is created by me but it is not working with morris charts, I don't know what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem.
reworked a response from PHP and used that variable as a data feeder to the chart:

```
    $chart_data = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $chart_data .= "{ dt:'".$row["dt"]."', totali:".$row["totali"]."}, ";
}
$chart_data = substr($chart_data, 0, -2);
?>
<script>
    Morris.Bar({
        element : 'chart',
        data:[<?php echo $chart_data; ?>],
        xkey:'dt',
        ykeys:['totali'],
        labels:['totali'],
        hideHover:'auto',
        stacked:true
    });
</script>
```